# Validations in EditorForModel MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a dynamic view which is rendered as PartialView from controller:

```
@model dynamic
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", null,  FormMethod.Post))
 {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.EditorForModel()

 <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}
```

When I hit the submit button, it should display validation message if anything is missing or any format is not correct etc.,

However, on hitting the submit button the post edit action is invoked before it shows the messages. Typical postback in asp.net terms, is happening. 
Shouldn't it show the errors on client side before executing server controller code?

I am bit confused, can somebody clarify is it the right way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you referred Jquery unobtrusive and validate script files?

Comment: i hve no clue..can u shed some light?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Content", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmIndex" }))
        { 

            <div>
                @if (Model.ID != 0)
                {
                    <label style="float: left;">
                        Id</label>
                    <input id="txtID-@Model.ID.ToString()" type="text" class="hide" value="@Model.ID.ToString()"/>
                }

            </div>
            <div>
                              @if (Model.Name != null)
                {
                    <label style="float: left;">
                        Name</label>
                    <input id="txtName-@Model.ID.ToString()" type="text" class="hide" value="@Model.Name.ToString()"/>
                }
                else
                {
                    <label style="float: left;">
                        Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("Name")
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("Name")
                }
            </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Save" style="float: left;" id="btnSave" title="btn" />
}
```

**Use this Script for validation**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btnSave").click(function () {

                var validation = $("#FrmIndex"); // My From Id
                if (!validation.valid()) {
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: mine is dynamic as I mentioned in the question. if I just include these scripts will it work?

Comment: Yes my page is also dynamic.

Comment: I have added the two scripts in my bundles but still the control is going to edit post action after that only it is displaying message. can u advise

Comment: @CodeCaster, I hve registered the scripts in bundle (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js,jquery.validate.min.js, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js ). In web.config I have the key "UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" set to True. I dont still on click of submit, the form is submitting and after that only I can see the message.I guess the message should show from client end.not sure what wrong I am doing

Comment: @mmssaann that should work. I cannot find how MVC unobtrusive validation works with a `dynamic` model, because everyone calls everything dynamic nowadays and search results are far from relevant.